# Attach elastic IP's to bastion hosts when provisioned automatically

Tags: ansible, yaml

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  roles:
    - provision_ec2

# this uses a variable defined in the first role of this playbook, provision_ec2.
- hosts: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].bastion_server_group }}"
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  roles:
    - hosts_file

# this won't work on bastion servers until we automate a way to connect to the newly provisioned bastion server.
# This would require some proxy command and attaching an elastic IP, then pushing that to the ssh_config.
```

Because now we do the above mention comments manually every time when we spin a new bastion server, I need your help to know how automate the process of  attaching the Elastic IP to the newly provisioned bastion server? I am new to Yaml and ansible, I am learning  yaml from last few weeks.

```
- hosts: '{{HOST_GROUP}}'
  gather_facts: False
  roles:
    - { role: ec2_tags, when: server_type != 'bastion' }
    - { role: ec2_tag_volumes, when: server_type == 'app' or server_type == 'util' }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [ec2_eip](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_eip_module.html) module. Use it just after creating your instance with `ec2` module.

Example usage:

```
-  ec2_eip:
     region: "{{ region }}"
     state: present
     in_vpc: yes
     device_id: "{{ ec2_result.instances[0].id }}"
     reuse_existing_ip_allowed: yes
```